# PHP compare totals from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The array presented below has values for three consecutive dates.  I am trying to calculate the difference between the total of the values from the first date, and the total of the values from the second date, and the total of the values from the third date.

Any suggestions on how best to accomplish this?  Thanks.

```
Array
(
[Nov 18, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => Array
            (
                [C] => Array
                    (
                        [T] => 50803.805765535
                    )
                [S] => Array
                    (
                        [T] => 32908.863528
                    )
            )
    )
[Dec 11, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => Array
            (
                [C] => Array
                    (
                        [T] => 31746.502038235
                    )
                [S] => Array
                    (
                        [T] => 16836.613004414
                    )
            )
      )
[Dec 24, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => Array
            (
                [C] => Array
                    (
                        [T] => 43524.786543288
                    )
                [S] => Array
                    (
                        [T] => 15722.772389011
                    )
            )
      )
)
```

Comment: "how best to accomplish this" --- can you implement it in any, even not in the "best" way?

Comment: I didn't get pretty much which arithmetical operations you need to perform:  "difference between the total of the values from the first date, and the total of the values from the second date, and the total of the values from the third date" it's pretty confusing. Did you mean total1-total2-total3?

Comment: and what does total mean? array[date][c][c][t]+array[date][c][s][t]?

Comment: i want to keep array[date][c][c][t] and array[date][c][s][t] separate.  i don't want to combine these values, but compare the changes from one date to the next.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is named $arr:

```
$totals = array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $val){

  $totals[$key] = $val['C']['C']['T'] + $val['C']['S']['T'];
}

print_r($totals);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem 100% correctly, but here's a try.  If the array is $a, array_value_recursive() function will extract just the values of 'T' for each date, then echo the difference between the two.  The output looks like:

```
Nov 18, 2011 (C 50803.805766 / S 32908.863528) - Dec 11, 2011 (C 31746.502038 / S 16836.613004) = C 19057.303727 / S 16072.250524
Dec 11, 2011 (C 32908.863528 / S 31746.502038) - Dec 24, 2011 (C 16836.613004 / S 43524.786543) = C 16072.250524 / S -11778.284505
```

The code is:

```
$keys = array_keys($a);
$values = array_value_recursive('T',$a);

for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++) {
    if (isset($keys[$i+$i])) {
        printf( "%s (C %f / S %f) - %s (C %f / S %f) = C %f / S %f\n",
            $keys[$i], $values[$i+$i], $values[$i+$i+1],
            $keys[$i+1], $values[$i+$i+2], $values[$i+$i+3],
            $values[$i+$i] - $values[$i+$i+2],
            $values[$i+$i+1] - $values[$i+$i+3] 
            );
    }
}

function array_value_recursive($key, array $arr){
    $val = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use($key, &$val){
        if($k == $key) array_push($val, $v);
    });
    return count($val) > 1 ? $val : array_pop($val);
}
```

**edit**: updated the loop and values after correcting